# Fluent nHibernate and interfaces

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Does fluent nHibernate play well when using interfaces instead of concrete classes as properties?

E.g. A sports stadium has a reference to a city that it is in, so our interfaces/concrete classes looks as follows

**Interface:**

```
ICity  
  int Id;  
  string Name;  

IStadium
 int Id;  
 string Name;  
 ICity City;
```

**Concrete class:**

```
class City: ICity;  
   ...

class Stadium: IStadium;
  public virtual int Id {get; private set; }  
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual ICity City { get; set; } //<- NOTE: Reference to interface instead of the class
```

**Mapper:**

```
public class StadiumMap : ClassMap<Stadium>
{
    public StadiumMap() 
    {
       ...
       References(x => x.City).Column("Id");
       ...
    }
}
```

So will the above work fine in fluent nhibernate or will I have to replace my "ICity" with "City"?

Answer (score 0):

A little off topic but I doubt your domain classes are benefiting from implementing interfaces. [James Gregory said it best](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845536/programming-to-interfaces-while-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate/845714#845714).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that link. That thread is indeed useful. However its not a case of if my domain classes are benefitting from implementing interfaces but its a case of "will it work"?. I will investigate the issue further drawing from a comment made further in the thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845536/programming-to-interfaces-while-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate/1130856#1130856